# Multiple, independent, instances of same wtform form on same page

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am playing with a project management application. I am looping the projects, the lists in side the projects, and the tasks inside each list. I would like the  CreateTask() form to appear for each list, under the tasks, and it does.

The reason is that I have 2 hidden fields, the project id and the list id.

The problem is that, while the forms are showing up correctly, if I enter a task name and submit all it does is refresh the page and every form has the text I entered into the first form.

How can I use the same WTForms form in multiple instances on the same page and have them work independently?

One form, with the project and list id's set to select fields, works. I am able to add tasks.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SelectField, TextAreaField, SubmitField, HiddenField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, ValidationError

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'f0c4803ba453fc7f8d0c43df21413916'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

##################################
######    Database Tables   ######
##################################

class Project(db.Model):
  p_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  p_title = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
  p_list = db.relationship('List', backref="project", lazy=True)
  p_task = db.relationship('Task', backref="project", lazy=True)

  def __repr__(self):
    return f"P('p_id: {self.p_id}','p_title: {self.p_title}','p_list: {self.p_list}', 'p_task: {self.p_task}')" 

class List(db.Model):
  l_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  l_title = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
  l_project = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.p_id'), nullable=False)
  l_task = db.relationship('Task', backref="list", lazy=True)

  def __repr__(self):
    return f"L('l_id: {self.l_id}','l_title: {self.l_title}','l_project: {self.l_project}')"

class Task(db.Model):
  t_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  t_title = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
  t_list = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('list.l_id'), nullable=False)
  t_project = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.p_id'), nullable=False)

  def __repr__(self):
    return f"T('t_id: {self.t_id}',' t_title: {self.t_title}','t_project: {self.t_project}')"


##################################
#####         Forms         ######
##################################

class CreateTask(FlaskForm):
  project = HiddenField('Project:', validators=[DataRequired()])
  list_select = HiddenField('List:', validators=[DataRequired()])
  task_title = StringField('Task Title:', validators=[DataRequired()])
  submit = SubmitField('Add Task')

##################################
######        Run App       ######
##################################

@app.route('/try', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
  form = CreateTask(request.values, project="foo", fld2="bar")
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    p_id = form.project.data   
    l_id = form.list_select.data   
    task = form.task_title.data
    new_task = Task(t_project=p_id, t_list=l_id, t_title=task)
    db.session.add(new_task)
    db.session.commit()
  project = Project.query.all()
  return render_template('index.html', form=form, project=project)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)




{% for item in project %}
  <div style="padding: 30px; maring: 30px; border: 1px solid #000;">
    <h2>{{ item.p_title }}</h2><br><hr><br>
    {% for item2 in item.p_list %}
      <h3>{{ item2.l_title }}</h3><br><hr><br>
      {% for item3 in item2.l_task %}
        <h4>{{ item3.t_title }}</h4><br><br>
      {% endfor %}
      <br><br>
      <div style="padding: 40px;">
        <form action="" method="POST">
          {{ form.hidden_tag() }}          
          {{ form.project(value=item.p_id) }}
          {{ form.list_select(value=item2.l_id) }}
          {{ form.task_title.label }}<br>
          {{ form.task_title }}<br><br>
          {{ form.submit }}
        </form>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't create two instances of the form, you just render the same instance twice.

So in app.py it should be:

```
def index():
    form1 = CreateTask(request.values, project="foo", fld2="bar")
    form2 = CreateTask(request.values, project="foo", fld2="bar")
    ...
    return render_template('index.html', form1=form1, form2=form2, project=project)
```

And the template has to be changed accordingly. You can put the two instances in a list if you want to iterate over them in the template.

But be aware that if you have several forms on a page only one form will get submitted. If you want to edit several items at once you need to iteratively generate a single form (at least if you don't add some JS magic).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I need the a dynamic number of forms based on the number of lists that exist?

Comment: Do you have this number in your view or is that something that changes while people input data.

Comment: The user can create projects, add lists to those projects, and add tasks in those lists. I am only working on the task form at the moment, which needs to exist for each list. Their is no limit or order to the amount of ltasks, lists, or projects.

Comment: But you could know the size of projects by doing len(projects) right? In that case you could just do something like for forms = [CreateTask(...) for item in len(projects)]. However you might want to use a single form for your view anyways since only one of the forms will be submitted.

Comment: Is wtforms not a good way to manage this? other task managers allow you to click into a text field, type, and add a task to a specific list. I assumed creating this form would be a good precursor to my single page application frame work by allowing the  user to click into a task and make a a form to update or change the title.

Comment: As long as you work with Flask template-based views every submit will send a request and render your page new. SPA are a totally different animal. You would generate your views entirely in JS and would interact with a REST API. As far as I am aware wtforms is not geared toward this. However, if you new to this the traditional web app approach might be actually better.